# Javascript making map access fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

Map size is around 2000 elements. When accessing the map with key's it works good on chrome but firefox crashes sometimes. Is there a way to map the access fast. I am using jQuery too.

```
var map=new Object();
map[1] =blah;
..
map[3000] =blah3000;
```

access randomly any element. What would be an optimal solution?

Comment: Does Firefox give any error message?

Comment: Regular stopscript and continue message. Works fine on chrome though.

Answer (score 1):

A 2000 item array? Sounds like what yous should be asking is ideas to reengineer whatever functionality you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know, we are going reengineer it. But need a temporary solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `Object` to `Array`, like this:

```
var map = [];
```

Comment: Sadly, javascript arrays are simply objects that use numerical strings as keys.  Though browsers might have some native optimizations for this, it will never be as fast as an array in something like C for instance.